# Callback after scanning Payconiq custom online QR code

Tags: qr-code, payment-processing

I'm looking to get a callback to my shop's backend after the client scans the payconiq QR code from the merchant frontend page.

More info about payconiq's payment flow can be found here: https://developer.payconiq.com/online-payments-dock/#payconiq-online-v3-custom-online

I thought i had 2 possible sollutions but both have some problems.

In the [first one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0rwg.png), the shown QR code leads to the backend of the merchant. Here I forward to the normal payment URL.
I tried this but stumbled upon 2 problems. When scanning with the payconiq app, it would say the QR code could not be processed. Probably because it's not a URL leading to their domain. When I scan the QR code with Google Lens (which i'd like to avoid because it's not intuitive), It leads me to the payment page but it doesn't open the app. Even though I forward to a deeplink.

[Solution two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hARL.png) would be to get a callback from the Payconiq backend when they receive a request for payment details. This one is not in my control and I don't think they would be flexible enough to change their API.

Does anyone has any solution to this problem or has a different strategy for this?

Answer (score 0):

When scanning the QR code, the status of the payment goes from "PENDING" to "IDENTIFIED". By polling the payment details, I was able to detect the scanning. I don't think it's very optimal so feel free to suggest another option.